# Android IntentService for Notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarm

I'm trying to make a service, that is completely independent from the activity and running all the time in background to send the notification about incoming event. I have solved the problem of service killing along with activity by returning START_STICKY value in onStartCommand. It works well, but then I have problem with sending notifications. The problem is in the setSmallIcon method. When i pass there the reference to R.drawable.ic_launcher, I have got error, which says, that icon == 0. Is there any way to make it work properly?

Here is my NotificationService.java

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

    private static final int UPDATE_TIME = 60 * 1000;

    private ArrayList<Group> groups;

    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotficationService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void showNotification(String name, int remindTime) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
          (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, n); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {      
        while(true) {
            checkForNotification();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(UPDATE_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your looking at service the wrong way. Intent Service works only with special cases like if there is work to do and then when no work it will quit itself. The doc says you should not implement OnStartCommand (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int) ). You must extend in the Service class to do long running work.

Comment: I'd stay away from using while(true) in Android. It will kill infinite loops and recursive threads. I think what you really want is a repeating alarm that sends an intent to your service at this UPDATE_TIME interval. Also, while intent service is meant to have a long life, its onHandleIntent() should be short. It is meant to reuse objects from the service's onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
.setSmallIcon(Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_delete))
```

instead of

```
.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, because the setSmallIcon method needs an integer or Icon object and here we have Drawable object.